# El ubuntu que instalé en virtualbox se quedó sin espacio

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

estaba haciendo algunas pruebas con [bazel](/questions/tagged/bazel) en un [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu), en concreto verisón `18.04.1 LTS` virtualizado en un [windows10](/questions/tagged/windows10) y no tiene ni una semana y ya me sale que está lleno, por lo que creo que es un error de virtualbox.

Salida de comandos

---

- df:

  ```
  Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
  udev             3313652        0   3313652   0% /dev
  tmpfs             668780     2860    665920   1% /run
  /dev/sda1       10253588  9619792     93228 100% /
  tmpfs            3343896        0   3343896   0% /dev/shm
  tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
  tmpfs            3343896        0   3343896   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
  /dev/loop1         14976    14976         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
  /dev/loop2          2304     2304         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
  /dev/loop0        146432   146432         0 100% /snap/chromium/516
  /dev/loop3          3840     3840         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
  /dev/loop4         90368    90368         0 100% /snap/core/5897
  /dev/loop5        492544   492544         0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-community/101
  /dev/loop7         13312    13312         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
  /dev/loop8         35456    35456         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
  /dev/loop9        493184   493184         0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-community/106
  /dev/loop11         2432     2432         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/180
  /dev/loop6          3840     3840         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
  /dev/loop12       144384   144384         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
  /dev/loop10        35584    35584         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
  /dev/loop13        89088    89088         0 100% /snap/core/4917
  /dev/loop14       144128   144128         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
  /dev/loop15       119040   119040         0 100% /snap/vscode/69
  /dev/loop16        46208    46208         0 100% /snap/core18/442
  /dev/loop17        14848    14848         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/37
  /dev/loop18        13312    13312         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
  IdeaProjects   494466044 68928712 425537332  14% /media/sf_IdeaProjects
  sharedwithvm   494466044 68928712 425537332  14% /media/sf_sharedwithvm
  tmpfs             668776       44    668732   1% /run/user/1000
  ```
- lsblk

  ```
  NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
  loop0    7:0    0   143M  1 loop /snap/chromium/516
  loop1    7:1    0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/45
  loop2    7:2    0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/260
  loop3    7:3    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
  loop4    7:4    0  88.2M  1 loop /snap/core/5897
  loop5    7:5    0   481M  1 loop /snap/intellij-idea-community/101
  loop6    7:6    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
  loop7    7:7    0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/103
  loop8    7:8    0  34.6M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
  loop9    7:9    0 481.5M  1 loop /snap/intellij-idea-community/106
  loop10   7:10   0  34.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
  loop11   7:11   0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/180
  loop12   7:12   0 140.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
  loop13   7:13   0  86.9M  1 loop /snap/core/4917
  loop14   7:14   0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
  loop15   7:15   0 116.1M  1 loop /snap/vscode/69
  loop16   7:16   0    45M  1 loop /snap/core18/442
  loop17   7:17   0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/37
  loop18   7:18   0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/139
  sda      8:0    0    10G  0 disk 
  └─sda1   8:1    0    10G  0 part /
  sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
  ```
- df -i

  ```
  Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
  udev           828413    456 827957    1% /dev
  tmpfs          835974    780 835194    1% /run
  /dev/sda1      655360 182153 473207   28% /
  tmpfs          835974      1 835973    1% /dev/shm
  tmpfs          835974      6 835968    1% /run/lock
  tmpfs          835974     18 835956    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
  /dev/loop1       1720   1720      0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
  /dev/loop2       1269   1269      0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
  /dev/loop0      10348  10348      0  100% /snap/chromium/516
  /dev/loop3        747    747      0  100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
  /dev/loop4      12808  12808      0  100% /snap/core/5897
  /dev/loop5      12441  12441      0  100% /snap/intellij-idea-community/101
  /dev/loop7       1597   1597      0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
  /dev/loop8      27345  27345      0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
  /dev/loop9      12442  12442      0  100% /snap/intellij-idea-community/106
  /dev/loop11      1272   1272      0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/180
  /dev/loop6        724    724      0  100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
  /dev/loop12     27638  27638      0  100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
  /dev/loop10     26698  26698      0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
  /dev/loop13     12842  12842      0  100% /snap/core/4917
  /dev/loop14     27631  27631      0  100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
  /dev/loop15     16806  16806      0  100% /snap/vscode/69
  /dev/loop16      8016   8016      0  100% /snap/core18/442
  /dev/loop17      1720   1720      0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/37
  /dev/loop18      1598   1598      0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
  IdeaProjects     1000      0   1000    0% /media/sf_IdeaProjects
  sharedwithvm     1000      0   1000    0% /media/sf_sharedwithvm
  tmpfs          835974     34 835940    1% /run/user/1000
  ```
- df -h

  ```
  Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  udev            3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /dev
  tmpfs           654M  2.8M  651M   1% /run
  /dev/sda1       9.8G  9.0G  328M  97% /
  tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /dev/shm
  tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
  tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
  /dev/loop0      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
  /dev/loop1       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
  /dev/loop2      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
  /dev/loop3      117M  117M     0 100% /snap/vscode/69
  /dev/loop4      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
  /dev/loop5      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
  /dev/loop6       46M   46M     0 100% /snap/core18/442
  /dev/loop7       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
  /dev/loop8       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/5897
  /dev/loop9      143M  143M     0 100% /snap/chromium/516
  /dev/loop10      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
  /dev/loop11      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
  /dev/loop12     2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
  /dev/loop13      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
  /dev/loop14     2.4M  2.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/180
  /dev/loop15      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
  /dev/loop16      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/37
  /dev/loop18     481M  481M     0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-community/101
  /dev/loop17     482M  482M     0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-community/106
  IdeaProjects    472G   66G  406G  14% /media/sf_IdeaProjects
  sharedwithvm    472G   66G  406G  14% /media/sf_sharedwithvm
  tmpfs           654M   32K  654M   1% /run/user/1000
  ```

El formato de mi archivo de imágen es `vdi`

**Qué he intentado**

`dpkg -l | grep linux-image-`

Y me arrojó:

```
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic              4.15.0-29.31                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic              4.15.0-42.45                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                        4.15.0.42.44                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

así que procedí a eliminar una de las imágenes de kernell usando el comando

```
sudo apt-get autoremove linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic
```

El espacio ganado fueron 179 MB así que sigo con el mismo problema.

Para descatar que fueran archivos de logs generados por bazel corrí el comando

```
bazel clean
```

en la carpeta del proyecto donde está el workspace.

Tras volver a correr `df -h` obtengo

> /dev/sda1       9.8G  8.5G  826M  92% /

Tras correr el comando `du -a /home | sort -n -r | head -n 10` que sugiere Bryro obtengo la siguiente salida:

```
1433096 /home
1433092 /home/ruslan
671492  /home/ruslan/Downloads
671488  /home/ruslan/Downloads/ideaIU-2018.3.1.tar.gz
604204  /home/ruslan/.cache
598516  /home/ruslan/.cache/bazel
598512  /home/ruslan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ruslan
598216  /home/ruslan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ruslan/install
305484  /home/ruslan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ruslan/install/3aadb0885b1cb52846820562c39bed63
305480  /home/ruslan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ruslan/install/3aadb0885b1cb52846820562c39bed63/_embedded_binaries
```

( Qué tampoco sé interpretar )

Comment: Dale un df -h; y luego un du -shc / para validar el peso de los archivos desde la raiz

Comment: @Bryro me sale 15G y eso que mi disco es de 10G, ¿debería de desmontarle las carpetas compartidas del sistema operativo antes de correr el comando?

Comment: Voy a tratar de verificar que no sea este problema: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/949

Comment: Si tienes una carpeta montada si deberias desmontarla

Comment: Mi partición no cambia: `/dev/sda1       9.8G  8.5G  825M  92% /
` y du me da 11G

Comment: Dale un du -a /home | sort -n -r | head -n 10 para verlo por carpeta e identifiques cual es la mas pesada y que tiene dentro

Comment: Y cúal es la más pesada? La última? :smile: